# How to solve "error splicing file" IO while copying files?

Tags: 12.04, files, clipboard

I've recently backed up some files on an external hard drive in order to install Ubuntu 12.04.

But when I wanted to copy the backed up files (ex. music files) back to home folder, I'm prompted with this:

```
error splicing file: input/output error
```

[image]

I'm unable to get my files back on my computer.

Comment: What is the formatting of device you copy from and of the location you want to copy it to? Also have a look at the end of `dmesg` and see if it has any extra information.

Comment: I have some music files I want to move in the music folder. Device format is FAT32. Also, please be more explicit about dmesg, is it a command line..? or..have no idea what it is. I used Disk Utility to find device formatting. hope this helps...

Comment: yes, check the files on the external media for weird characters (or characters that might be special like \, /) that might screw up your copy. Oh and also try to tar the directory and see if you can untar it at the location you want it (that one helped me a few times)

Comment: Never thinked about archiving, I'll try that!

Comment: error while adding files to archive. no other details. Also, all characters are normal. I wonder if there's anything else to do...

Comment: It could be the disc ... maybe do a chkdsk from windows on the fat32.

Comment: oh boy, I'm sorry, but I don't have windows. I should go to a friend. I use fat32 because of accesibility. I tryied moving individual files, archiving, moving files together, same result. What if I make use of ubuntu one? :))

Comment: What are the file sizes you try to move? I experienced similar errors while I was moving files bigger than 4.7Gigs.
I created archives with a max file size of 2.5Gigs, that did the trick for me.

Comment: @iulian Can you try copy the file to a folder that don't have comma `,` it its name?

Comment: I have the same problem while using the USB 3.0 port. When I connect the drive to USB 2.0 port it copies with no error.